# How to convert matplotlib.pyplot.contour to RGBA list or array?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to convert the information from a contour plot into an array or list in RGBA so that I can combine that information with another image using PIL.

So far, I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

#Inputs for plt.contour
x = numpy.linspace(0,x_size,x_size)
y = numpy.linspace(0,y_size,y_size)

#Image data that will be used to make the contour plot.
image = Image.open(image_name)
image = image.resize((x_size,y_size))
image = image.convert("RGBA")
image_data = image.getdata()

#converts image_data from a 1 by (x_size times y_size) array to an x_size by y_size array.
Contour_Input = []
Vector = []
for i in range(x_size):
    for j in range(y_size):
        Vector.append(image_data[i*x_size + j])
    Contour_Input.append(Vector)
    Vector=[]

fig = plt.contour(x,y, Contour_Imput, 3, colors = '#000000', linewidths  = 1.5);
```

The problem I have is I now have this QuadContourSet but I need the RGBA information from it.

I had a workaround where I saved the contour plot as a Dummy.PNG file and then reopened it using Image and got the data that way, but I am sure there has to be a way to get the data directly without needing to save the dummy file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.